# LitElement - wait finish rendering

Tags: javascript, rendering, lit-element

I want to execute the timeout after my component completely render. that's not happening and I dont know why 'cause in the lit lifecycle updated comes after render.

```
updated(changedProperties) {
        if (sessionStorage.getItem('something') && !changedProperties.has('loading')) {
            !this.something ?
                setTimeout(() => {
                    document.querySelector('#something')?.click()
                }, 2000)
                :
                console.log('something')
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's hard to tell from your code what it is you want happening. `updated()` should run after the component renders. I'd suggest checking that the lifecycle method runs and it's not your condition or the selector that's not working.